# SimpleDateFormat is one day ahead

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am trying to show a date with a `SimpleDateFormat`. My problem is, if I'm formatting 31/08/2017, which is a Thursday (in France), is displayed as Friday. It does this for every day.

I first get a date in a **DatePickerDialog** :

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private OnPickerSet mListener;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    mListener.onDateSet(new Date(year,month,day));
}

public void setOnPickerSetListener(OnPickerSet listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
}
```

**Date**

```
class Date extends java.util.Date {

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM", Locale.FRANCE);

public Date() {
    // I don't want it set here
}

public Date(int year, int month, int day) {
    super(year, month, day);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
    return formatter.format(this);
}
}
```

I'm not doing any calculation with my date, so I don't understand why?

Comment: Are you trying to format as date `this`?

Comment: Please show how you are creating the `Date` that is being formatted.

Comment: It's a class extending java.util.Date, I'm overriding its toString method

Comment: What's the value of `getTime()` then? Are you only overriding `toString()` or some other methods (that maybe might affect this result)?. If that's the case, please **[edit]** the question and add more information there

Comment: Try with a normal Date object, do you get the same error?

Comment: With a "new Date()" I got "jeu. 24 août"

Comment: Without the entire code of your class i can only imagine that the timezone of your class is different from the timezone defined in the format. Remove the timezone in the format and retry.

Comment: Are you sure you have the year right? A wrong year would be a way to get a wrong day-of-week.

Comment: As an aside, I noticed your comment `// I don't want it set here`. When you are not explicitly calling a superclass constructor, Java calls the no-arg `Date()` constructor for you, which in turn gives you the current date and time. So if you expected a date that is not set, this is not what you get.

Comment: Also not completely to the point, but worth mentioning: You may want to consider leaving the outdated classes `Date` and friends behind, getting [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and starting using the modern Java date and time API instead. It’s generally much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to modify the constructor of your `Date` class

```
super((year-1900), month, day);
```

More about this in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date())

Second, you have to remove from the `toString` method the line

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
```

Third, and more important, abandon the whole idea of extending a class with so much deprecated methods and constructors. You can put the format code in an utility class and get the Date class from the calendar using the method `Calendar.getTime()`.

Comment: Agree that one should by all means avoid using the deprecated three-arg constructor in `java.util.Date`. It is unreliable, especially if the device’s time zone setting is not the same as the `Europe/Paris` used in the code. Is this also the reason why you want that line removed?

Comment: I'm not sure if `DatePicker` works with values 0-11 or 1-12 for month - so maybe you also need to do `month - 1` (January is month `0`, one more reason to avoid this terrible API...)